# WPF - view and RDLC report file

Tags: wpf, rdlc, documentviewer

I have an extensive WPF application and I now want to incorporate some reports. I understand how to create the reports with RDLC but what about viewing them? Ideally, I'd like to use the DocumentViewer but I don't think that's one of the supported file types. Some articles have suggested using the ReportViewer, but I do not have that as a control in my IDE (VS Pro 2008).

Is there a way to "convert" RDLC to XPS and then use the DocumentViewer or what is the best way for a WPF application to view an RDLC report?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the Open-Source .NET WPF Reporting Engine on [codeplex](http://wpfreports.codeplex.com)

Answer (score 6):

The MicrosoftReportViewer control is a Windows Forms control. You can use the WindowsFormsHost control to "host" the report viewer control in WPF, as [documented here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/4bbb9baf-6b0c-4a9f-a81e-6597a275338e).

Comment: I was hoping to get a different answer because I don't want to go down that road, but I thank you nonetheless.